# Reinterpret an array with uint8 elements to an array with uint16 elements

Tags: arrays, c

I want to reinterpret, (reinterpret, not reassign) a full array of uint8 elements as an array with half the elements but uint16.

PLEASE, NOT FOR-LOOPs.

The idea may be far-fetched (and it may be to look for the hair of the egg or the fifth leg of the cat), but I am using an 8-bit microcontroller and the DMA is 8-bit, I want to save CPU (for quaternion and kalman) using the right DMA especially on 12 ADC channels, which sample fast and I don't want to interrupt the microcontroller for latencies etc.

For example, to join two uint8s into one uint16, I know of several ways to reinterpret without making moves or reassignments.

```
typedef union { 
    struct {
        uint8_t uL;
        uint8_t uH;
    };
    uint16_t y;
} combined8_t;

combined8_t myADC[6];

myADC[0].uL = adcBuff[0];
myADC[0].uH = adcBuff[1];

uint16_t myUint16ADC = myADC[0].y;
```

or another form:

```
uint16_t myUint16ADC = (uint16_t)(*(uint16_t *)&adcBuff[0]);
```

these shapes reinterpret, my question is: is it possible to reinterpret the complete vector of uint8 into a complete vector of uint16?

i.e. for example:

```
uint8_t adcBuff[4] = {0x23, 0xAB, 0xA6, 0xB4};

uint16_t adcBuff16[2] = {0xAB23, 0xB4A6};
```

without using loops, only pointers or unions, and as far as possible that it is resolved in a line of code and that it generates the least assembly code possible.

Best regards, thank you very much.

I was able to do something like this, and it is working, but I had to edit a file that I shouldn't edit as it is automatically generated by MPLAB Code Configurator.

```
typedef union{
uint8_t adc8_t [24];
uint16_t adc16_t[12];
}combined16_t;

combined16_t adcBuff;
```

In the DMA configuration Destination Address : &adcBuff.adc8_t

```
DMAnDSA= &adcBuff.adc8_t;
```

--------In my Main code---------

```
usSRegHoldBuf[1] = adcBuff.adc16_t[0];
usSRegHoldBuf[2] = adcBuff.adc16_t[1];
usSRegHoldBuf[3] = adcBuff.adc16_t[2];
```

With this union, the DMA of the ADC converter saves the high and low part of the conversion in an array of 24 elements uint8, and I access it as an array of 12 elements uint16.

But I don't want this solution, I don't want to edit the file, I want to be able to reinterpret it from outside. If I already have the 24 element vector uint8, how can I reinterpret it as a 12 element uint16? Please, solutions that are not intrusive to the CPU.

Thanks.

Comment: PLEASE, no use memcpy, memcpy use loops. I need use only pointers or unions for the entire uint8 array to reinterpret as uint16 array. Thanks.

Comment: How to reinterpret an array of uint8 to another array of uint16 without data movement?

Comment: `uint8_t uL; uint8_t uH;` This suggests a little-endian machine. But then your example is wrong, and bytes `0x23, 0xAB` would mean short integer `0xAB23`, not `0x23AB`.

Comment: Yes, not problem, is only a example, I wrote it lightly, it goes backwards, but that's not my question. I want to know more ways to reinterpret, and if it is possible to reinterpret an array without making data movements, make it as efficient as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Simply `uint8_t adcBuff[] = {...};` `uint16_t *adcBuff16 = (uint16_t *)adcBuff;`.

Comment: I will try it right now, I hope it works, thank you very much !!!!!

Comment: dxiv, THANKS!!!!, It works perfect, it was what I was looking for, it did it for variables, but it had not occurred to me for arrays. Million of thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped, but careful there. It may work in this case because some untold assumptions about endianness and alignment happen to check out in your environment. But it would not necessarily work everywhere and all the time.

Comment: Yes, I understand the endianness issue, if it didn't work, I would ask the DMA to decrement the counter cyclically, to take ADRESH first instead of ADREL. It currently reads ADREL, increments and reads ADRESH, cyclically. Thanks!

Comment: This `uint16_t *adcBuff16 = (uint16_t *)adcBuff;` will probably not cause any problem on your 8bit micro. But in general (mainly on any machine with >8 bit CPUs) you can run in trouble due to `adcBuff` not being aligned properly for 16bit accesses.

Comment: Sure, of course, I make sure to put the array in a memory address with enough contiguous space to be able to do the reinterpretation. And explicitly ask the compiler to do it in an aligned way.